# How to open Eclipse with attached console in OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I need to launch my Eclipse RCP application with the terminal attached to it and cannot do this. Eclipse itself has the same problem. I have added the standard "-console" option to eclipse.ini but the console is not shown. However when I run  `Contents/MacOS/eclipse` directly it works and shows the console! What is the difference in thse two ways of launching and why doesn't the simple way show the console?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to use -consoleLog parameter? -console sets osgi console port, so it is rather not what you want.